# How to save and display video using C# in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, video, save, ckeditor

I am developing a website project with CMS using C#, also I am using Ckeditor to save data to SQL Server. How can I save video from YouTube in the database and display it on the webpage?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to save? URLs, or whole video files? Also save and display are two separate questions. Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Trying to save URLs